# From uint to decimal

Tags: decimal, uint16

I'm getting data from an ADC through SPI: I save the data into an array of type uint16_t and I use a terminal to see the result.

How can I see this result in decimal instead of unsigned int?
I need to know if the values I get are what I really want.
My code is in C.

```
uint16_t mVals[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; printf("%u\n\r", (unsigned)mVals[0]
```

This is how I print.
But i would like to see number in decimal on the terminal.
I even have a write function to have the printf working:

```
int _write(int FD, char buffer, int len){
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t)buffer, len, 1000); return len;
}
```

Marc

Comment: Hi! Can you show some code about the problem?

Comment: uint16_t mVals[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; printf("%u\n\r", (unsigned)mVals[0]. This is how I print. But i would like to see number in decimal on the terminal. I even have a write function to have the printf working: int _write(int FD, char *buffer, int len){

 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)buffer, len, 1000);
 return len;
}